# Can I sell bitcoin worth five million dollars or more and how can I?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, sell-bitcoins

I bought 200 bitcoin in the year 2012 and I've come to the point where I feel I need to withdraw some of it. But I'm having some difficulty doing that. How can I withdraw a large sum of bitcoin and where? An answer preferably includes a step by step guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first [fifteen](https://coinmarketcap.com/de/rankings/exchanges/) exchanges here are famous and credible. Choose one of them, open an account, verify your ID (KYC would certainly be required), add your IBAN number, deposit Bitcoin, sell it, withdraw it to your account.

Answer (score 1):

Contact OTC desks (Maybe [HodlHodl](https://hodlhodl.com/) team can help you) or do it in installments on exchanges like [Bisq](https://bisq.network/)

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye on the tax in your country. In Germany for example you have to store Crypto on one exchange or wallet for about one year, so you dont have to pay taxes.
But if you just once traded crypto in that year you have to pay tax for the profit you made.